# EditText.setText() Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext

I have this NPE that is driving me crazy, maybe it's just "tunnel vision" but I can't solve it. I have a fragment inside an activity, and in the activity's `onCreate()` I instantiate fragment. Then later when the fragment is added to activity I call fragments method from the activity. The code is below

```
transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.ActionInputFragment, settingsFragment).addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();

if(jsonUserData != null)
  settingsFragment.loadUserData(jsonUserData);
```

In the fragment I have:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        this.ctx = getActivity();

    edtFullName = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.edtFullNameSettings);

    edtFullName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher .....);
}
```

Adding the textwatcher works. Below (in the same fragment) is the method whose call generates the error:

```
public void loadUserData(JSONObject jsonUserData) {
        String fullName;
        try {
            fullName = String.format("%s %s", jsonUserData.getString("first_name"), jsonUserData.getString("last_name"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            fullName = "";
        }
        //if(edtFullName != null)
            this.edtFullName.setText(fullName);

    }
```

I have checked the layout and the editText id is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that `this.edtFullName` is not yet **initialized** because `onActivityCreated` is not called yet thus `edtFullName` is null upon calling `setText()` method

You can pass the reference of the `EditText` in the `loadUserData` instead in the `onActivityCreated`

Comment: I think I got it. Thank you very much. I cannot pass in a reference but I can make the method call not necessary by taking the work to the fragment. Thank You. I will accept you answer as soon as I can, but consider expanding it a bit for future visitors :D

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin How to pass the reference of edittext to that method?